# how to change font family on positive or negative button on react-native-simple-dialogs plugin

Tags: react-native, plugins, dialog

I'm using react-native-simple-dialogs for taking confirm. but I have a problem and I don't know any solution for this. I trying to change the font family, and it doesn't change. what is the solution?

Comment: is the font system supported ? if not then you have to link it to the project

Comment: Did that font work correctly in other parts of your app? If you are sure about correct font linking, please add a pice of your code here.

Comment: yes, it works and I haven't got any problem. but I realized, in this plugin, font family totally doesn't work.

Comment: I realized, we can change native code in the plugin and using a custom font instead of the font itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can give the right answer.

because you don't share the code, but I'll write down my answer on the assumption that you registered `your custom font`.

If you are trying to resolve something with one button, use the `status` value.
And it can be solved using the Conditional operator.

```js
this.state = {
   buttontext : "nomal"
}
      <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.button}
         onPress={this.onPress}
       >
         <Text style={{ fontFamily: this.state.buttontext == "positive" ? "customfont" : this.state.buttontext == "negative" ? "customfont" : "nomalfont"}}>
         {this.state.buttontext}
         </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: this is for the normal button in react native, but I have a problem with react native simple dialogs plugin buttons. you must study this plugins document. but whatever thank you bro

Comment: I can help if you tell me which module you are using.

Comment: Im using react-native-simple-dialogs . I said that.

Comment: In this case, you can use the font that fits the button. What's the problem?